# How to make functions/method work together in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, methods

for some reason in the following code the fadein method doesn't work while the first function works perfectly. How do I make them work together?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function updown() {
        $("#freccia")
            .animate( {"top": "+=20px"}, 2000, "easeInOutQuad" )
            .animate( {"top": "-=20px"}, 2000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        updown();
    }

    updown();

    $("#frontespizio")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000);
});
```

Comment: you forgot to declare it as a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
     updown();
     fadeMe();     
});

function updown() {
    $("#freccia")
        .animate( {"top": "+=20px"}, 2000, "easeInOutQuad" )
        .animate( {"top": "-=20px"}, 2000, "easeInOutQuad" );
}

function fadeMe() {
    $("#frontespizio")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000);
}
```